# Console Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple counter that runs in the JavaScript console / Firebug. How can I set the thresholds? (hours = 24, minutes = 59, seconds = 59, milliseconds = 999)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4fdZ/)

```
/* Code missing, link is dead and not archived */
```

Comment: hours should be `= 23` right ? (*not `= 59`*)

Comment: I finally got around to that demo. Have a look.

Comment: @Gaby Yes you're right. Sorry, it was late night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`%` modulus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29)

```
console.log(h%24 + 'h ' + m%60 + 'm ' + s%60 + 's ' + ms%1000 + 'ms');
```

example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/p4fdZ/2/

> The modulus operator returns the first
>   operand modulo the second operand,
>   that is, var1 modulo var2, in the
>   preceding statement, where var1 and
>   var2 are variables. The modulo
>   function is the integer remainder of
>   dividing var1 by var2. For example, 12
>   % 5 returns 2. The result will have
>   the same sign as var1; that is, −1 % 2
>   returns −1.

Comment: +1 since modulo is technically the correct way to implement the "threshold."

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! This is very simple, I thought it will be harder (like the previous answer).

Answer (score 6):

You can't actually rely on your `setInterval()` call to run every single millisecond. Because of this, you're **much** better off just using [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)* to get the millisecond value every time the function runs. This will solve your "thresholds" problem as well.

[om nom nom, demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/VXhsv/1/)

In the mean time, read [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

---

*or `new Date()`

Comment: @Nyuszika: true, it's not as "easy" as the answer you accepted, but it is the **correct** and **accurate** implementation. But you really can't rely on the browser calling your functions at the exact intervals you specify - especially with your 1-ms increment function. Browsers generally have minimum delays. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Comment: I know, but I'm making these fiddles for myself, and it works fine in my browser. Certainly, I should test my HTML, CSS, JS on all major browsers when I'll make a web page, but that's the future.

Comment: **Update:** It seems that the milliseconds are too slow, but I don't need them, so I modified it to count only hours, minutes and seconds, with an interval of **1000 ms**, which will probably work on all (major) browsers

Comment: @Nyuszika: yes, the 1 second interval will be pretty close to what you expect, as long as you're not running tons of JS that will delay the `setInterval` callbacks. But I just noticed - **are you trying to profile your code?** If so, use `console.time('timerName')` and `console.timeEnd('timerName')`! http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.time.28name.29

Comment: I know about this, but I want a counter that prints out the current status every second to the console, certainly with clearing the previous message.

**Note:** I deleted my previous fiddle, and Gaby's forked fiddle was lost with that, too. Sorry.

Comment: @Nyuszika: "profiling" == analyzing performance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)